# Mysql hangs forever after initial installation on Windows 10 with chocolatey

Tags: windows, mysql, chocolatey

So I got a new work laptop - it's a fresh dell latitude - and windows 10 went through a very nice set up phase. I proceeded to install all the things.

- git (for windows)
- VSCode
- chocolatey
- keepass
- dropbox
- nodejs (latest, 8.4.0)

So I pop open Git Bash as an administrator and run:

```
cinst mysql -y
```

Then I try, several times, to get `mysql` or `mysql -u root` to work. So I read online on the chocolatey package MySQL needs the vscredist2013, so I `choco uninstall mysql`, install the redist, then reinstall MySQL. I try `mysql -u root` again - no dice.

Then I make sure MySQL service is actually running, *it wasn't* so I started that service, then I try again with `mysql -u root` - it still hangs forever now :c

[Here's a gist of the .err file MySQL generates](https://gist.github.com/snewell92/ecf69fce37aec828795cf4fc69c86006). Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot further or what went wrong?

Oh, I just pressed `ctrl-c` to kill the MySQL command and a new line was added to the .err file:

> 2017-08-23T19:39:59.126983Z 3 [Note] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'lo  calhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Which I suppose seems normal - I just don't know what it was even trying to do that whole time :\

Thank you so much for reading <3<3

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot and some more twiddling I decided to not use chocolatey to install, put rather the [official installer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html) from oracle. You need an oracle account, but it's free. And the installer lists and checks the requirements before installing - so that's nice.

If anyone else has any luck *with chocolatey* please post! I guess some requirements just weren't met...?